# Flutter: GoogleMaps Preview Dialog

Tags: google-maps, flutter, flutter-layout

Can you help me? I need some ideas whats components or library need to use for create expandable view like google maps in Flutter.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use this: https://pub.dev/packages/sliding_up_panel

Tis library will help you to create slidind up panel ;)

Comment: Thank! It looks like I wanted =)